# Clearing and resizing tables in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that I use to display data. I want it to change its size depending on the size of the data that is to be displayed. I already implemented that part.

However, I am having problems with cleaning the table afterwards. I want to write a function that **clears all the fields in the tables DataBodyRange and resized it to 1 without changing anything else in the table**. I would also like to not rely on code like

```
Worksheets("Sheet").ListObjects("table").Resize Range("B13:K15")
```

that uses reference to certain static cells like B13 or K15, as moving the table would break the function if I used that.

What I am looking for is more a "Resize the DataBodyRange to 1 row". How would I do that?

**EDIT:**

**Daghan's answer basically does what I want, however, I cannot select my tables DataBodyRange any more after using the cleanup function.**

My code:

Cleanup-function:

```
Sub clearAllocationsView()
    Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").Resize Range("table[#All]").Resize(2, 10)
End Sub
```

Table fill function:

```
Sub getAllocations()

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    Set t = Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").DataBodyRange
    data = transposeArray(cn.Execute("select * from some_table").GetRows)
    t.Resize(UBound(data, 1) - LBound(data, 1) + 1, UBound(data, 2) - LBound(data, 2) + 1) = data

End Sub
```

Where transposeArray is just a self-written transpose function because VBA standard transpose has problems with null values.

To give more detail for the current situation: my table fill function works (filling the data and resizing the table depending on data size), the cleanup function works, however, after calling the cleanup function I can no longer call either the table fill or the cleanup function, both error with

> object variable with block variable not set

regarding the DataBodyRange of the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
Worksheets("Sheet").ListObjects("table").DataBodyRange.ClearContents

Worksheets("Sheet").ListObjects("table").Resize Range("table[#All]").Resize(2, 10)
```

Where 2 is the header+ 1 data row (the minimum for tables).

Where 10 is the amount of columns from B to K.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code does what I want. However, there is a problem: I cannot call this function twice. Actually, I can't re-fill my table either after I call your function. The problem seems to be that after cleaning the table with your function, it can't find the DataBodyRange anymore. To be more precise, I get the error 'object variable with block variable not set' which, when debugging, 'showsWorksheets("Sheet").ListObjects("table").DataBodyRange ' as the variable that is not set. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Could be multiple things. Try posting your code in the question.

Comment: Try  `Resize(3, 10)`

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, it works with 'Resize(3, 10)', although it then of course resizes to 2 rows instead of 1. This is not the end of the world, however I would really prefer if I could resize it to 1 row. Any idea how this could be achieved or where I could find that information?

Comment: Yes, ideally what you want to do, is resize "3" to the `count`of rows of whatever you are inserting to the table.